# Switching Primary Gmail Accounts

Tags: email, gmail

I currently use a Gmail account as my primary email address (myemail@gmail.com). I have an email address linked with my site (andrew@mydomain.com) that currently forward to my existing Gmail account. I would like to instead make the andrew@mydomain.com my primary email address. I believe the steps I need to take our as follows:

1. Add andrew@mydomain.com as a Gmail email address
2. Add andrew@mydomain.com to my Mac Mail account
3. Forward all past emails at myemail@gmail.com to andrew@mydomain.com (through Gmail I presume)
4. Set myemail@gmail.com to forward to andrew@mydomain.com

It may be a very simple change, but I want to make sure I am doing it correctly before I begin considering how important zero downtime is for email. If you have any thoughts on the process or any suggestions, I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be able to get andrew@mydomain.com to check all your emails at myemail@gmail.com via POP/IMAP by going to Settings->Accounts and Import. I tried the forward route before, but it didn't work as I anticipated but the POP/IMAP worked like a dream for me.

BONUS INFO:
If you do use that method I highly recommend you get this plugin for Chrome and/or FF to check your POP/IMAP account's more regularly than "whenever Google feels like it" http://www.danielslaughter.com/projects/gmail-pop3-checker-for-greasemonkey/